# what's the difference in usage between gairaigo and wago?

Tags: loanwords

Please help me to understand how and when english-derived words are used in modern Japanese?
I understand that ko-hi and garasu didn't exist in Japan, so there are no Japanese words for them. But I found that there exist gairaigo for such words as "knife" and "husband" and many others, which obviously exited as phenomenons BEFORE .
So, could you please explain and give examples from your experience? Which words are preferable where? 
Are they all interchangeable, can they be used in scientific speech/text, in formal speech/text?

バカンス/休暇

ビル/建物

チケット/切符

ファイナル/最後

ママ/おかあさん

ミルク/牛乳

バッグ/鞄

ゼロ/零

アルバイト/働き

サラリーマン/社員

ドイツ/独国